# Ctrl+Alt+Del crashed the whole system

Tags: 14.04, crash

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Ubuntu 16.04 version system, by accident, when the system was not responding.

After that the system immediately crashed , and after restarting several times, it boots up, but while logging in into any of the user, it just blanks out the screen.

Is this a software problem from the Ubuntu kernel; because the hardware is working fine?

Comment: "*the hardware is working fine*": did you test with another OS?

Comment: with the other OS(Windows) , I am able to log in , but the system is laggy and so is the display. Before this error happened , a Ubuntu screen propped up saying some socket layer error.

Comment: So this is not exactly "*The hardware is working fine*". First thing first, run as much autotest as you can in the BIOS, including memory tests. The Linux boot screen usually includes a memory test as well. Also check if Windows reports the expected RAM size.

Comment: Thanks for it input. It was incorrect of me to assume that the hardware is working fine. There was an issue detected in the memory test, as the laptop was old. It was discarded anyways. So the old laptop was the culprit and not the old ubuntu 16.04 OS.